# run winexe on linux in order to exe CLI commands on WIN server ( workgroup server )

Tags: linux, windows, command-line-interface, remote-access

winexe is tool that can execute commands on WIN machines from Linux servers

winexe syntax should be as the following:

```
      winexe -U [Domain/]User%Password //host command
```

Because I have windows 7 that work as workgroup, I can defined in winexe syntax the domain name

**question:** is it possible to use the winexe without the domain name ? , or maybe there are some magic ideas that can help me with this case ?

**Usage**

winexe started without arguments shows list of options, 
using "--help" will show their descriptions. Most of the tasks can be done using syntax:

```
   winexe -U [Domain/]User%Password //host command
```

Where 'host' can be given as ip number or DNS hostname and 'command' is a command which will be run on remote system.

**Examples:**

```
 # winexe -U HOME/Administrator%Pass123 //192.168.0.10 "ipconfig /all"

 # winexe -U HOME/Administrator%Pass123 //host 'cmd /C dir C:\'
```

domain name - HOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Domain/" between `[` and `]` means it is optional, so this should work:

```
winexe -U User%Password //host command
```

If that does not work use the target hostname as Domain:

```
winexe -U host/User%Password //host command
```

This works because windows uses its local user database when domain = hostname. Maybe `./User%Password` (notice the dot) also works. The dot as Domain means "lookup your own database", too.

Comment: No I already try this its not work if domain not set in the winexe command

Comment: Have you tried to use the target hostname as domain?

Comment: what you mean as domain the target host is the IP address of the WIN server ?  , give me example so will try .

Comment: when your target host is `//targethost` use `winexe -U targethost/Administrator%Pass123 //targethost command`

Comment: I add the targethost in /etc/hosts and with his IP address and run this: winexe -U $targethost/Administrator%Pass123 //192.9l.22.19  , now its work - but how can exaplin this ? , I mean how the $targethost IP works in place of domain name ?

Comment: updated answer.